# Conditional rows to single rows mysql

Tags: mysql

**Table1:**

```
    event               | time                       |id          | user 
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ADDMEMBER           | 2017-06-14 08:03:58.872908 | 2335797    | x    
    REMOVEMEMBER        | 2017-06-14 09:17:02.719318 | 2337422    | x  
    ADDMEMBER           | 2017-06-14 09:28:23.343281 | 2337737    | x  
    REMOVEMEMBER        | 2017-06-14 09:46:50.189582 | 2338117    | x
```

My desired output would be 1 row per group of ADDMEMBER and REMOVEMBER :

```
    event               | Login                      | Logoff                     |user 
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ADDMEMBER           | 2017-06-14 08:03:58.872908 | 2017-06-14 09:17:02.719318 | x    
    ADDMEMBER           | 2017-06-14 09:28:23.343281 | 2017-06-14 09:46:50.189582 | x
```

I have no clue how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you show us the SQL that you tried along with the result that it gave?

Comment: Pls describe how do you pair addmember and removemembers with each other. There is no session identifier in your data, only user id. If you can only use user and the time information, then is it possible to end a session without a removemember event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `ADDMEMBER`, `REMOVEMEMBER` events are *always* paired, then you can use the following query to get `Login`, `Logoff` times:

```
SELECT 'ADDMEMBER', 
       MIN(`time`) AS Login,
       MAX(`time`) AS Logoff,
       user
FROM (             
   SELECT event, `time`, id, user,
          @grp := IF(event = 'ADDMEMBER', @grp + 1, @grp) AS grp                  
   FROM mytable
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @grp := 0) AS v
   ORDER BY `user`, `time`) AS t
GROUP BY user, grp;
```

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/ERV86585)